# extension method for List<T> is not accepting List<int>

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I'm currently experimenting with extension methods. My goal is a extension method for List which finds the first element that fits the given element in a collection, after a specified index.

```
public static class Extensions
    {
        public static T FindFirstAfterIndex<T>(this List<T> list, int index, T item) where T : class                                                                                    where T : struct
        {
            return list.Skip<T>(index).Where<T>(result => result == item).First<T>();
        }
    }
```

so this works for class objects as T.

I also tried:

```
public static T FindFirstAfterIndex<T>(this List<T> list, int index, T item) where T : class          
                                                                             where T : struct
{
    return list.Skip<T>(index).Where<T>(result => result == item).First<T>();
}
```

I'm very new in the generic stuff an T so how can i define my where clause to accept also `List<int>` ?

regards Mark

Comment: Why did you add that clause in the first place?

Comment: It is not visible in the snippet but your code actually contains *two* where clauses.  Was that intentional?  You may want to use none and use result.Equals(item) instead.

Comment: god, to many good answers....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your extension method in invalid in terms of its constraints:

```
   public static T FindFirstAfterIndex<T>(this List<T> list, int index, T item) 
       where T : class  where T : struct
```

(The `where T : struct` constraint is scrolled all the way over to the right on your question.)

You can't specify two constraint clauses for the same type parameter like this. You can specify *one* constraint clause with multiple constraints (e.g. `where T : class, IDisposable`), but it can't include both the `class` and `struct` constraints.

If your extension method *really* only has one constraint and that constraint is `where T : class`, then that explains why it's not valid for `List<int>` - because `int` doesn't satisfy the reference type constraint.

Frankly your method would be better off written like this:

```
public static T FindFirstAfterIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list,
                                       int index, T item)
{
    return FindFirstAfterIndex(list, index, item, EqualityComparer<T>.Default);
}

public static T FindFirstAfterIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list,
                                       int index, T item,
                                       IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    return list.Skip(index)
               .Where(result => comparer.Equals(result, item))
               .First();
}
```

Now it will work for *any* list, and will use the default equality semantics of `T` (which will make it work more conventionally for `List<string>` for example) and also allow you to supply a custom equality comparer when you want to.

Comment: +1 for `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` but I've always been curious, for what value of `T` would not `==` not be valid?

Comment: @Davy8 It's not a matter of not being valid. It's that different IL is generated for `==` depending on the types of the operands (even ignoring operator overloading.) Restricting `T` to a reference type avoids that. (Note that restricting `T` to be a `struct` *doesn't help*, since the tricky code-gen issue is still present.)

Comment: @Davy8: There are very strict rules around where you can use `==` to compare types of generic values. Unless there's a `T : class` constraint, you can only compare with `null` - and *with* the `T : class` constraint (and no others) it will simply perform a reference identity comparison.

Comment: Is it an implementation difficulty or is there something more fundamental about it?

Comment: that's really nice. Thank you!

Comment: @Jon: How is it not a question of not being valid?  It seems to me that == cannot be applied to a not-otherwise-constrained struct; doesn't that count as invalid?  For example, the following code gives the compiler error "...cannot be applied to operands of type T and null": `public static class E { public static bool Q<T>(T a, T b) where T : struct { return a == null; } }`

Comment: @phoog Bad choice of words. Obviously it's invalid; what I meant to get across was that the reason it's invalid is because the generated code becomes ridiculous (and essentially "non-generic") if the compiler allowed it without the constraint.

Comment: Jon, yes of course, sorry.  @dlev, thanks for clarifying.  My point, however, is that == is not allowed on (not-further-qualified) structs while Equals() is; many people seem to be unaware of that.

Comment: @dlev and (I forgot to mention) that the reason for disallowing == is because there's no guarantee that a struct implements the == operator.

Answer (score 6):

int is not a class.  int will be boxed into a struct (Int32).

You'd have to remove the clause:

```
where T : class
```

Or use `Int32?` instead.

**Update:**

`Int32?` will most likely not work, since technically it will still be a struct:

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
```

Your best bet is to remove the class constraint if you want to use structs here.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted (edit: must've been a misclick, gone now)

Comment: @Davy8 Probably because `int32?` doesn't satisfy the `where T : class` constraint. Also, `int` and `Int32` are the same thing in C#. `int` is an alias for the type `System.Int32`. And also generics actually *avoid* boxing value types; that's one of the reasons they're awesome!

Comment: `Int32?` wouldn't satisfy the constraint either, btw - `where T : class` requires `T` to be a reference type, not just a nullable type.

Comment: yeah i know that int is not a class :) sry the example above brings some misunderstanding i think. I only get it error free working when i add a constraint. I want that my extension method can accept List<MyClass> and also List<PrimitiveType> like int, double ....

Comment: Hmm yea I think you're right - Int32? just builds a Nullable<Int32> correct?  I will update!

Comment: Classes are *not* passed by reference (by default). References are passed by value. But `int?` (aka `Nullable<int>`) is still not a reference type.

Answer (score 6):

Just drop the `class` constraint:

```
public static T FindFirstAfterIndex<T>(this List<T> list, int index, T item) 
{

}
```

Comment: when i'm removing the constraint i get an error "Operator '==' can not be applied to operands of type "T" and "T". "

Comment: @Mark: You can use `result.Equals(item)` instead

Comment: @BrokenGlass: That will now fail if any item is null. It's better to use an appropriate equality comparer, IMO - see my answer.

Comment: ok... that works, i should had think of equals... so but only to lets fit that in my head ;) why is "Where<T>(result => result == item)" not working ?

Comment: @Mark: See the comments on Jon Skeet's more principled solution

Comment: yeah i was not quick enough with typing ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T FindFirstAfterIndex<T>(this List<T> list, int index, T item)
        where T :IComparable
    {
        return list.Skip<T>(index).Where<T>(result => result.CompareTo(item)==0).First<T>();
    }
}
```